# ui-sortable-handle class is added to edit.php WordPress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I see that the class ui-sortable-handle is added in the http://test.com/wp-admin/edit.php

```
<tr id="post-2442" class="iedit author-other level-0 post-2421 type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-media-releases ui-sortable-handle">
</tr>
```

How can I remove the class **ui-sortable-handle**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery it is easy:

```
$('#post-2442').removeClass('ui-sortable-handle');
```

**EDIT**

Globally

```
$('.ui-sortable-handle').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ui-sortable-handle');
});
```

**EDIT 2**

In wordpress you have specific classes in your `body` like `page-id-1`.

```
if($('body').hasClass('page-id-1')) {
    $('.ui-sortable-handle').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-sortable-handle');
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to remove this class globally

Comment: Thanks! How can I acheive this for a specific page?